# The Writer monad and its type declaration

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, typeclass, writer-monad

I am trying to get a better understanding of Monads and I am currently looking into the Write Monad in http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#writer

I don't understand its type declaration that seemingly consists of two types, nor do I understand its type constraint.

In the examples they specify that:

```
newtype Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (a, w) }  

instance (Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w) where  
    return x = Writer (x, mempty)  
    (Writer (x,v)) >>= f = let (Writer (y, v')) = f x in Writer (y, v `mappend` v')
```

In action it looks like this:

```
ghci> runWriter (return 3 :: Writer String Int)  
(3,"")  
ghci> runWriter (return 3 :: Writer (Sum Int) Int)  
(3,Sum {getSum = 0})  
ghci> runWriter (return 3 :: Writer (Product Int) Int)  
(3,Product {getProduct = 1})
```

But why does it return `Writer String Int` rather than a tupple of these elements, I wonder?

Could I have made a Monad type (e.g. Writer2) that would return `Writer String Int Float` ?

Furthermore it confuses me why the instantiation only takes `(Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w)` rather than `(Monoid w a) => Monad (Writer w a)` . And why isn't the `w` listed in the Monad binding and return methods, like `a` would be included in the type signatur for the type constraint `(Num a) => ...` This might be because I have some conceptual shortcoming in this area.

Comment: *"why does it return `Writer String Int` rather than a tupple of these elements"* What do you mean by 'it'? The three GHCi examples you've listed return tuples.

Comment: Yes, and that is what confuses me I think. Why isn't `runWriter (return 3 :: Writer String Int) ` written as `runWriter (return 3 :: Writer (String, Int))` or  does this have to do with the `newtype`-declaration?

Comment: @Piskator That's correct: `newtype Writer w a` indeed defines `writer` taking two type arguments: `w` and `a`, so you need to pass them both if you want the result be a type.

Comment: But what about (Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w) why the monoid type constraint, and why not Monad (Write w a) given the declared newtype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help your confusion if you replace the more generic `Writer String` with the more concrete `StringWriter`:

```
newtype StringWriter a = StringWriter (a, String)

instance Monad StringWriter where  
    return x = StringWriter (x, "")  
    (StringWriter (x, v)) >>= f = let (StringWriter (y, v')) = f x
                                  in StringWriter (y, v ++ v')
```

> But why does it return `Writer String Int` rather than a tuple of these elements, I wonder?

A `Writer String Int` is just another way to say a tuple `(Int, String)`. Look at the signature of `runWriter`, it converts from a `Writer String Int` to `(Int, String)`:

```
runWriter :: Writer w a -> (a, w)
```

and the data constructor `Writer`, which converts into the reverse direction:

```
(a, w) -> Writer w a
```

> Could I have made a Monad type (e.g. `Writer2`) that would return
> `Writer String Int Float`?

I am not exactly sure what you mean by that but for a monad it is essential that it works for all types, so the `a` in `StringWriter a` is important, when you declare the monad instance. (Confusingly enough, you need it but don't write it: `instance Monad StringWriter`.)

> Furthermore it confuses me why the instantiation only takes `(Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w)` rather than `(Monoid w a) => Monad (Writer w a)`.

A couple of points:

- `Monoid w a` does not make sense, since the [`Monoid` typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#Monoid) has only one parameter:

  ```
  class Semigroup a => Monoid a where
  ```
- `Monad (Writer w a)` does not make sense, because the argument to the [`Monad` typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#Monad) is not a type but a type constructor (with one argument). This is in contrast to the `Monoid` typeclass which takes a concrete type (instead of a type constructor of one parameter). That is, `instance Monad StringWriter` is correct but `instance Monad (StringWriter Int)` is not. Note that `StringWriter Int` is a type but `StringWriter` is a type constructor taking one argument.

> And why isn't the `w` listed in the Monad binding and `return` methods, like `a` would be included in the type signature for the type constraint `(Num a) => ...`

It is not listed, because the function type declarations are not listed. You could enable the [`InstanceSigs` extension](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/instances.html#instance-signatures-type-signatures-in-instance-declarations) and write them explicitly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

instance (Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w) where

  return :: (Monoid w) => a -> Writer w a
  return x = Writer (x, mempty)  

  (>>=) :: (Monoid w) => Writer w a -> (a -> Writer w b) -> Writer w b
  (Writer (x,v)) >>= f = let (Writer (y, v')) = f x
                         in Writer (y, v `mappend` v')
```

Comment: Thank you for a very clear answer, I think this answers all my questions.  StringWriter is also part of the normal Contral.Monad library?

Comment: The reason why my questions seems to be in  very different areas is because I might not be entirely sure what it is that confuses me. But I think what you wrote especielly about Monad vs Monoid helped clear things up abit.

Comment: No, StringWriter is not part of the library.  It's just an example to make it easier to think about `Writer String`.