# newtypes in Haskell with more than one arguments

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, console, ghci

In Haskell I try to call the following two `newtypes` that have I have declared.

Why does this work:

```
newtype CharList = CharList { get2CharList :: [Char] } deriving (Eq, Show)   

ghci> CharList "some"    
CharList {get2CharList = "some"}
```

When this does not work:

```
newtype Pair a b = Pair { createPair :: (a, b) } deriving (Eq, Show)

ghci> Pair 2 4
<interactive>:13:1: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type: t0 -> t
                  with actual type: Pair a0 b0
    * The function `Pair' is applied to two value arguments,
        but its type `(a0, b0) -> Pair a0 b0' has only one
      In the expression: Pair 2 4
      In an equation for `it': it = Pair 2 4
    * Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:13:1)
```

Does it require a Monad to work as seen here: [The Writer monad and its type declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74412227/the-writer-monad-and-its-type-declaration)
And will I necessarily then have to constraint the type when calling the `newtype`

Furthermore, how can I go about it if I want a `newtype` to take even more arguments such as 3?

Comment: You can always create a pattern synonym, `pattern ThePair a b = Pair (a, b)`

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What will that do exactly?

Comment: With [PatternSynonyms](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html?highlight=patternsynonyms#extension-PatternSynonyms) you can abstract over data constructors. You can still use a newtype with an uncurried constructor `Pair :: (a, b) -> Pair a b` but you can define a curried variety of it through the pattern synonym above: `ThePair :: a -> b -> Pair a b`. That way you can leverage `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` while having a more ergonomic constructor.

Comment: The link you posted seems to be broken. But what you are suggesting is that I can create a patternsynosym as specified and it it willl allow me to call (e.g.) `ThePair 2 4` and `Pair 2 4` will be returned.

Comment: The link works for me, https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/pattern_synonyms.html. Using the code you wrote you can not write `Pair 2 4`, you must write a tuple `Pair (2, 4)`. The my suggestion you can write `ThePair 2 4` and it translates it into `Pair (2, 4)`.

Comment: A newtype only wraps a single type. If there is no need to use a newtype then just write: `data Pair a b = MkPair a b`. That allows you to write the constructor like you wanted `MkPair 2 4`. Or you can define a pair of 3 values `data Pair3 a b c = MkPair3 a b c` and you can construct it directly: `MkPair3 True True False`.

Comment: Ok, it seems I have understood it correctly then. Thank you. NB: Weird the new link you have posted works for me how as well (both versions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Pair` newtype is declared as containing (or wrapping) a tuple of values, so that's what you must supply to create a value:

```
ghci> Pair (2, 4)
Pair {createPair = (2,4)}
```

You can extract the tuple from a `Pair` value with `createPair`:

```
ghci> createPair $ Pair (2, 4)
(2,4)
```

While the *type* is given as `Pair a b` (without brackets or comma), the *data constructor* requires a tuple. The type is declared to the left of the equal sign, and the data constructor is to the right.

The syntax `Pair (2, 4)` is just shorthand for the full data constructor, which is also possible:

```
ghci> Pair { createPair = (2, 4) }
Pair {createPair = (2,4)}
```

You can create wrappers with more type arguments in the same way:

```
newtype Triple a b c = T { getTriple :: (a, b, c) } deriving (Eq, Show)
```

This example also showcases something that may help understanding the above. The name of the type doesn't have to be the same as the name of the data constructor. Here, the name of the type is `Triple`, while the name of the data constructor is `T`.

You create a value of `Triple` using the data constructor `T`:

```
ghci> T (1, "foo", True)
T {getTriple = (1,"foo",True)}
```

The *type* of that expression is:

```
ghci> :t T (1, "foo", True)
T (1, "foo", True) :: Num a => Triple a String Bool
```